# Postgres PDOStatement::errorInfo() driver specific error message persists across queries

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, php-pgsql

I've encountered the following bizarre behavior:

```
//assume $dbh is a valid handle
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET myintcol = :myintval");

$stmt->bindValue(':myintval', 'notanint', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());

$stmt->bindValue(':myintval', 123, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
```

This will output:

```
Array ( [0] => 22P02 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "notanint" ) 
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "notanint" )
```

Although the 2nd execution succeeds, as indicated by the `00000` SQLSTATE error code and by checking the actual table for the update, for some reason element 2 of this array, what the docs call "Driver specific error message", retains the previous message. This seems to plainly contradict the docs for `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) which state that it will "Fetch extended error information associated with the **last operation on the statement handle**".

Does anyone have any explanation? It's not a showstopper it just seems like a bug.

Comment: Update on this question. I have exactly the same behavior and I don't understand how to fix it.